# Getting Order to Appear on Confirm Alert Box

Tags: javascript, html, function

So I got this function:

```
function displayTotal() {
                var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to place this order?");
                if (r == true) {
                    x = "Your order has been placed!" + document.forms["drinkList"].reset();
                } else {
                    x = ""
                }
            }
```

What I am trying to do is get the total cost of all items ordered, along with what item, quantity, and price per item.

I am using this function for example, to get the total for a particular drink.

```
var totalEstimate = 0;
var blackCost = 0;

function calcBlack() {
                totalEstimate -= blackCost;
                blackCost = document.forms.quant1.value * 0.99;
                totalEstimate += blackCost;
                document.drinkList.order.value = "$" + totalEstimate;
            }
```

I have tried:

```
function displayTotal() {
                var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to place this order?" + calcBlack());
                if (r == true) {
                    x = "Your order has been placed!" + document.forms["drinkList"].reset();
                } else {
                    x = ""
                }
            }
```

But that didn't display anything. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

I am calling `displayTotal()` here:

```
<input type="button" value="Order" name="order" onclick="displayTotal()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calcBlack` doesn't return anything, you'll need to modify it to return the data you want to display in the `confirm` alert box.

```
function calcBlack() {
    totalEstimate -= blackCost;
    blackCost = document.forms.quant1.value * 0.99;
    totalEstimate += blackCost;
    document.drinkList.order.value = "$" + totalEstimate;

    return totalEstimate;
}
```

Comment: Ah, can't believe I forgot that. Thanks. But now once I did that, I tried again and now the alert box doesn't show up. I tried adding calcBlack() and calcBlack(totalEstimate) within the displayTotal() function.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 Are you using your browser's developer tools? I suggest looking at the output on the Javascript console - I suspect you have some sort of syntax error in your js code.